# Automatically adjustable column in bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap grid framework i have 6 column in my table and based on condition those column will appear or disappear. Suppose I hide 3 columns from the database. Now I can see only 3 column in my table , but they are not arranged properly. I want these 3 column should be adjustable automatically in my table. Using angular JS to get the column labels and data for my application.
I am new in bootstrap, any help would be commendable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have columns that are generated in the run time then you can set the width accordingly or set the bootstrap grid class.

Suppose you have 3 columns then you will add class `col-md-4` to those columns, each adding up to 4 (width of the column) * 3 (columns) = 12 (the max col-size as specified in the [bootstrap grid documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/)). If you have generated 2 columns only then you can set class `col-md-6`.

You can do this calculcation in your javascript code.

Comment: In This case, how you are suggesting for odd no. of column.

Comment: If you want to adjust the width equal for all the columns then you can specify percentage value to the width of the column, total width will be 100% and divided by number of columns.